# How to resolve invalid host header issue in webpack?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, jenkins, webpack-dev-server

I'm getting invalid host header error, if i access my page through browser with online ip. Locally it is working perfectly, but i don't know why this error is coming in live server. I'm following three steps to run my react js application, that is,
'npm install'
'npm run build'
'npm run serve'

**webpack config file host setup**

// replace localhost with 0.0.0.0 if you want to access
// your app from wifi or a virtual machine

```
const host = process.env.HOST || '0.0.0.0';
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

const stats = {
  hash: false,
  version: false,
  timings: false,
  assets: false,
  chunks: false,
  modules: false,
  reasons: false,
  children: false,
  source: false,
  errors: false,
  errorDetails: false,
  warnings: false,
  publicPath: false,
  colors: {
    green: '\u001b[32m',
  },
};
```

**package.json scripts**

```
"build": "rimraf build && cross-env NODE_ENV=production webpack --env.prod=true --env.sw=true",
    "serve": "pushstate-server build/ 3000",
```

Answer (score 1):

Webpack dev server has recently had a host check added by default as a security measure https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-server/releases/tag/v2.4.3

You will now need to either disable it via `disableHostCheck` option (not wise if publicly accessible) or specify the public host or IP that you will be accessing it at when starting the server `--public your-hostname-or-public-ip:3000`

EDIT: Webpack in question name and webpack-dev-server tag was misleading - this actually uses different server altogether...

Ah it looks like this is not actually webpack related at all - you are using a different server `pushstate-server` which strangely has the host option in the module, but is not exposed in the binary. You will have to roll your own server startup script to pass a different host to it (it is 0.0.0.0 by default).

Save this to `./server.sh`

```
#!/usr/bin/env node

require('pushstate-server').start({
  directory: process.argv[2],
  port: process.argv[3],
  file: process.argv[4],
  host: process.argv[5]
}, (err, address) =>
  console.log(`Listening on port ${address.port} (http://${address.address}:${address.port})`)
)`
```

Change your npm script change to

`server.sh build/ 3000 index.html your-publicly-accessible-hostname`

Comment: Is this format is correct? "serve": "pushstate-server build/ --public localhost:3000".

Comment: Updated in answer edit above, as turns out its not webpack releated at all

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error when I came across to these:

https://help.crossbrowsertesting.com/faqs/testing/invalid-host-header-error/

In my case it was solved by **restarting the service.**